# NotificationCompat - Cannot prevent restart

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

I want to prevent system from restarting my app when user click on notification and app is in foreground yet.

My tests:

```
      1) adding android:launchMode="singleInstance"
      2) adding intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
      3) Modifying flags using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, or FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
      4) changing PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to 0 (zero)
```

Nothing. Every time I click on notification app restart. But i want to prevent it if i'm in app.

Here my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(service, Main.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            aggregation,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    manager.notify(
            aggregation,
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    service,
                    Type.isMessage(push.getEnumType())
                          /*mycode*/
                    .setCategory(category)
                    .setWhen(push.getWhen())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(pending)
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
                    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_LARGE)
                    .setNumber(number)
                    .setStyle(style)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build());
```

Comment: Maybe you should remove all flags that you set programmaticaly to intent and just keep singleInstance mode in your manifest?

Comment: thanks @НиколайГольцев. Deleting flags and adding singleinstance on my manifest nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got it.

`PendingIntent` once created remain in the system until you reboot the system (I'm not sure about this case) or uninstall your app.

The simple solution in your case is about two steps:

1) As I said you should remove this line of code:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

and define this behaviour through manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

2) Replace `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` with `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` to update `PendingIntent` every time you call it's constructor.

**Important thing: I suggest you read `PendingIntent` documentation to understand in details how it works.**

Comment: Thanks, now work correctly. I will read PendingIntentDocumentation.